# Unsupported operand types for bitwise exclusive OR in Python

Tags: python, bitwise-or

I am working with a function which generates cyclical redundancy check values. on data packets prior to sending them out over serial and I seem to be having some problems with the Python not being able to determine the difference between a hex representation and an ascii representation of a value.  I send the following data:

```
('+', ' ', 'N', '\x00', '\x08')
```

To the following function

```
# Computes CRC checksum using CRC-32 polynomial 
def crc_stm32(self,data):
    crc = 0xFFFFFFFF
    for d in data:
        crc ^= d
        for i in range(32):
            if crc & 0x80000000:
                crc = (crc << 1) ^ 0x04C11DB7 #Polynomial used in STM32
            else:
                crc = (crc << 1)
    crc = (crc & 0xFFFFFFFF)
    return crc
```

Now the actual value of the '+' char that is going through this function is (as one might expect) 0x2B, however when Python gets to the line

```
crc ^= d
```

I am faced with the following error

> unsupported operand type(s) for ^=: 'long' and 'str'

I have tried casting the value to chr(), hex(), int(), long() etc. all to no avail.  It seems as though Python is interpreting the '+' value as a char or string.

Comment: Python is a strongly typed language. Every single object in your `data` is a string, but the bitwise operators require `int` objects. I'm assuming you want `for d in map(ord, data):`

Comment: Are you using Python 3? If so, `data` should be bytes, not a string. Your code will then work as-is.

Comment: @Blender `data` *could* be a `bytes` object, or a `bytearray`. It is currently a tuple, though. Anyway, the `'long'` implies Python 2.

Comment: @chepner iterating a memoryview should give you into, at least in Python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per juanpa's comment, the following modification to the code allowed for the proper handling of the data.

```
    # Computes CRC checksum using CRC-32 polynomial 
def crc_stm32(self,data):
    crc = 0xFFFFFFFF
    for d in map(ord,data):
        crc ^= d
        for i in range(32):
            if crc & 0x80000000:
                crc = (crc << 1) ^ 0x04C11DB7 #Polynomial used in STM32
            else:
                crc = (crc << 1)
    crc = (crc & 0xFFFFFFFF)
    print crc
    return crc
```